# MSDN SocketAsyncEventArgs exapmle: how many threads are created?

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

I look at MSDN [SocketAsyncEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) example and cant quite get how many threads will be created in case of 100 infinitely writing onto us clients?

Or better if we'd change `ProcessReceive` into some form of communication protocol that talks to clients and reads back infinitely will all our `ProcessReceive` be in 100 separate running threads or will be somewhat alike Unity3d routines in one thread?

I am so interested because haven't seen in that example any direct thread related code except `Semaphore`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is "it depends".  `SendAsync`, `AcceptAsync`, and `ReceiveAsync` use asynchronous IO and completion ports.  This is done with an independent thread pool for IO threads.  This operates similarly to the "other" thread pool--it has a minimum and maximum.  The default maximum for the IO thread pool is 1000 [1] So conceivably the example could go as high as 100 threads.

The thread pool creates threads, as needed, in a wait state and as asynchronous IO completes these threads are taken out of the wait state to process the result.

But, in reality it depends on when packets are sent and when packets are received.  Conceivably if all the responses to all the sends occurred sequentially, it could be as low as 1 thread.  But, that's likely pretty rare.  In reality the closest you could really estimate is between 1 and 100 threads, inclusive.

You could test this by keeping track of `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` for each asynchronous operation.

The important thing to remember is that the Completed event is raised on a thread pool thread and that regular thread-safety precautions should be taken (e.g. use of `Semaphore`).

[1] Joe Duffy, *Concurrent Programming on Windows*, 2008, Addison-Wesley Professional